# EM scattering cross section, antenna directivity and its interpretation

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength, scattering-cross-section, antennas

The formula (35.25), see [Slater](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.15368/page/263/mode/2up?view=theater), $\bar A_r = \frac{\lambda^2}{4\pi}$ is probably the most important formula in radar  and/or antenna engineering. It says that the average absorbing cross section of *any* **matched** antenna is independent of the radiating structure. Here the emphasis is on **matched** that is one antenna whose impedance is conjugate (resonant) matched to the single-mode waveguide connecting it to its absorbing load and it may be a single frequency match at which the antenna is designed to operate.

Now, this is really a very surprising result because it says that antenna directivity (ie., radiation pattern) is not directly dependent on the *size* of the antenna as one would have assumed naively. In fact, an arbitrarily small dipole has exactly the same radiation pattern as a larger one ($\ell <\lambda/2$), while its complex radiation impedance is, of course, a strong function of the length. This is surprising because it implies that in certain directions a radiating structure has larger effective size than its physical (geometrical) size.

So, how does a small antenna work? How can the energy of the wave be absorbed by something that is not local to it? Is it possible that this is a *macroscopic* manifestation of the quantized nature of absorption/generation of the EM waves? The "wave size" of the antenna is lower limited by $ \approx \lambda/2$ at which level the *granularity* of the interaction becomes apparent.

Comment: Not an answer, so I'm writing as a comment. Two points 1) You can take this to an extreme as an "ideal" dipole is a 1 dimensional construct and has zero area! 2) I would find it hard to argue this is an effect of quantization as this result come from a purely classical theory.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome It maybe a failure of classical physics the way it lead to nonsensical result of Rayleigh-Jeans for the black body radiation. While I have no problem accepting that an arbitrarily small radiator (dipole or otherwise) could be perfectly matched to *transmit* without loss at a vanishingly narrow frequency band I find the reverse statement, that is the same infinitesimally *small* antenna could also be matched in its *receive* mode to a plane wave. This is just beyond bizarre. We may be combining the principles of reciprocity, singularities and Chu's theorem illegally...